# Расположение элементов списка в две колонки

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер!

Помогите сделать так, что бы этот список был в два столбца

```html
<ol>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
</ol>
```

Должно получиться как-то так:

```
 1 _____    6 _____
 2 _____    7 _____
 3 _____    8 _____
 4 _____    ...
 5 _____
```

Comment: @Air, я думаю, что не стоит так бурно реагировать) Да, вопросы часто плохо оформлены, но обычно достаточно указать на это минусом, голосом за закрытие и **доброжелательными** рекомендациями ТС-у по поводу улучшения вопроса)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, учту на будущее)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
  counter-reset: cntr;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: cntr;
  content: counter(cntr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Чего минусите-то?)

Comment: минус скорее всего за то, что используете ul вместо ol

Comment: @soledar10 ну в таком случае стоит сперва попробовать как оно работает с нумерованным, а потом минусить.

Comment: я минус не ставил, а наоборот + поставил

Comment: @soledar10 да я понял, но авось вредители читают комментарии

Comment: @websnap, а как оно работает с нумерованным? У меня так же, как с ненумерованным.

Comment: Решено, спасибо!

Comment: looks like костыль

Answer (score 1):

*Попытка №2*

### Вариант №1

```css
ol {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 2.5em;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2.5em;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 3em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
</ol>
```

### Вариант №2

```css
 ol {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaKxgO отличное решение.

Comment: @websnap проверяй

Comment: видишь как оно получается: сначала самому подучиться надо, потом других носом тыкать.
И да, флексы по-прежнему для сеточных блоков, а не для текста.

Comment: @websnap по примеру написано 10 li сделал на 10

Comment: Исправил вам оформление. Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь инструментами по назначению. Заголовки должны быть заголовками. А разметку html+css удобнее делать в сниппете (кнопка "фрагмент кода")

Comment: @PavelMayorov не знал как делать такие штуки "в сниппете"  до сегодняшнего дня.   Не плохо, рахмет!

Comment: @Даниил это вы меня так обозвали? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да :)  [перевод](https://ibb.co/enR9hb)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает в хроме, в других браузерах не проверял:

```css
ol {
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 0; /* Убираем стандартное зарезервированное под номер
                      элемента место, потому что оно только для первой
                      колонки подходит. */
}

li {
  margin-left: 2em; /* Резервирование места под номер. */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.list {
  column-count: 3;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.list p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Минус за то что вы потеряли нумерацию и семантику, притом одновременно.